# How to install apache on a Raspberry Pi 2 Ubuntu Snappy Core?

Tags: apt, apache2, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I installed Snappy Ubuntu Core on a Raspi, hoping to use it as a webserver, however I can't apt-get install packages and snappy install has virtually no packages available (right now). Do I have to manually compile and set up everything without any package management? Then what's the point of snappy if there is no software available for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this stage you have 3 options:

- Use one of the basic webserver example given in the Ubuntu Core documentation
- Build Apache for Ubuntu Core (i.e create your yaml file and go through the packaging process)
- Use a Docker container on Snappy and install Apache in this container

We're just at the beginning of Ubuntu Core and still need help porting applications like Apache webserver to it (basically repackaging). Any help repackaging application would be appreciated! We're trying to publish as much of the new applications ported on the developer.ubuntu.com/snappy feel and always welcome demand for new packages to be ported.